# Changing chart properties

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I've been following the tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196502/WPF-Toolkit-Charting-Controls-Line-Bar-Area-Pie-Co?msg=4209801#xx4209801xx) for the development of a pie chart. I have it working just like it shows.

My problem is that my chart is updated upon button press and each time, it changes colors. My question is, can I prevent this color change?

Also, can I have the chart display it's actual values? In the instance of the chart shown, in the legend it would show "Developer - 60". There's not a whole lot of documentation that I've seen for the extended toolkit. And what there is, I haven't found a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

After much and more searching, I never found any documentation on the items I was looking for, but I did find [this project](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/507#.Ubnb_fnbPng), which is a way to add labels to the pie chart itself. I'm still working on how to maintain colors, but these labels so far work for displaying the values, as well as pointing to the part of the pie chart that it's associated with.